# Negar secuencia en RegExp y coincidir lo que se negó

Tags: javascript, regex

Quiero hacer una expresión en RegExp, en el primer grupo que coincida todo hasta que aparezca `*/`, en el segundo grupo, que coincida `*/`.

```
grupo    texto      expresión   escapado
  1      "hola "     (?!*/)     (?!\*\/)
  2       "*/"        (*/)       (\*\/)
```

Lo que intenté fue lo siguiente, pero me sale `null`:

```js
console.log(
"hola */".match(/(?!\*\/)(\*\/)/g)
)
```

Ejemplos:

```
expresión        resultado

"hola */  */"    "hola */"
"hola */"        "hola */"
"hola *  */ */"  "hola *  */"
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado?¿Puedes poner un ejemplo del match?

Comment: @davidbug Quiero que capture toda la expresión. `"hola */"`

Comment: @davidbug Edité la pregunta.

Comment: prueba con esta expresión regular:  /.*?\*\//g  , el punto equivale a cualquier carácter y seguido del * hace que se repita hasta que encuentre a "*/". El símbolo "?" hace que termine al encontrar el match mas corto.

Comment: corrección:  /.*?\\*\//g

Comment: @davidbug Funciona perfecto, puedes ponerlo como respuesta si quieres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para esto hay que usar el signo de pregunta luego del asterisco `.*?`:

```
/(.*?)(\*\/)/g
```

- Para el primer grupo es `(.*?)`
- Para el segundo grupo es `(\*\/)`

Se puede usar split para separar cada grupo.

Código:

```js
console.log( "hola */".split(/(.*?)(\*\/)/g) )
```